# need to access variable outside the stop_show function

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I want to access the `spw` and `wps` variable outside the `stop_show()`
can someone please help me on this. I want to import this variable into another function from a different module.

```
from tkinter import *
import time

para = "India is one of the youngest superpowers in the world.\n The National bird of India is the peacock, which has\n a very colourful and beautiful tail. The national flower of\n India is Lotus. Lotus comes in many colours, white and pink \nbeing prominent.The National animal of India is the Royal\n Bengal tiger."

words = len(para.split())

# Stop watch code starts:

def start():
    global start_time
    start_time = time.time()

def stop_show():
    global end_time
    end_time = time.time()
    global elapsed_time
    elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
    print(f"Time elapsed: {round(elapsed_time, 2)}")
    wps = words/elapsed_time
    spw = elapsed_time/words
    print(f"Your current WPS (Words per second): {round(wps, 2)}")  
    print(f"Your current SPW (Seconds per word): {round(spw, 2)}")  

# UI code:

root = Tk()

para_label = Label(root, text=para, bg="red",
                   font="comicsansms 23 bold", width=100, height=10)
para_label.pack(fill=X)

Start_btn = Button(root, text="Start", command=start,
                   fg="red", width=25, height=5)
Stop_btn = Button(root, text="Stop", fg="red",
                  width=25, height=5, command=stop_show)

Start_btn.pack(anchor=S, side=TOP)
Stop_btn.pack(side=TOP, anchor=S)

frame = Frame(bg="grey", )

root.title("Readzy")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You use `global`, exactly as you did with `end_time` and `elapsed_time`.

Comment: How do you access those variables inside *another function from a different module*?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options here, first is to make it class based and modify the attribute of the class.
Second is easier, just make it global variable and use global keyword.

```py
wps = 0
spw = 0

def stop_show():
    global end_time
    global wps
    global spw
    end_time = time.time()
    global elapsed_time
    elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
    print(f"Time elapsed: {round(elapsed_time, 2)}")
    wps = words/elapsed_time
    spw = elapsed_time/words
    print(f"Your current WPS (Words per second): {round(wps, 2)}")  
    print(f"Your current SPW (Seconds per word): {round(spw, 2)}")

def unrelated_func():
    print(wps)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `frame.pack()`. And your widget is not anything for `frame`. And because you cannot see grey background.

**It is warning not to use** `from tkinter import *`.

Code using snippet from @WingedSeal:

```
import tkinter  as tk
import time

para = f"India is one of the youngest superpowers in the world.\n The National bird of India is the peacock, which has\n a very colourful and beautiful tail. The national flower of\n India is Lotus. Lotus comes in many colours, white and pink \nbeing prominent.The National animal of India is the Royal\n Bengal tiger."

words = len(para.split())

# Stop watch code starts:

def start():
    global start_time
    start_time = time.time()

wps = 0
spw = 0

def stop_show():
    global end_time
    global wps
    global spw
    end_time = time.time()
    global elapsed_time
    elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
    print(f"Time elapsed: {round(elapsed_time, 2)}")
    wps = words/elapsed_time
    spw = elapsed_time/words
    print(f"Your current WPS (Words per second): {round(wps, 2)}")  
    print(f"Your current SPW (Seconds per word): {round(spw, 2)}")


root = tk.Tk()

frame = tk.Frame(bg="grey")
frame.pack()

para_label = tk.Label(frame, text=para, bg="red",
                   font="comicsansms 23 bold", width=100, height=10)
para_label.pack(fill=tk.X)

Start_btn = tk.Button(frame, text="Start", command=start,
                   fg="red", width=25, height=5)
Stop_btn = tk.Button(frame, text="Stop", fg="red",
                  width=25, height=5, command=stop_show)

Start_btn.pack(anchor=tk.S, side=tk.TOP)
Stop_btn.pack(side=tk.TOP, anchor=tk.S)

 
root.title("Readzy")
root.mainloop()
```

Output:

[image]